# updated ID column still failing with RangeError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an autoincremented ID field in my app which has reached the upper limit of 2147483647 for a medium int in mysql. I receive the following error:

RangeError: 2147483656 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4

I created a migration to make the ID a bigint:

```
change_column :my_model_names, :id, :integer, limit: 8, auto_increment: true
```

This appears to have worked - here is the description of the field from the mysql command line:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                          | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the rails console, I can see that the column looks correct when I query MyModelName.columns:

```
2.2.2 :045 > MyModelName.columns[0]
> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::Column:0x007f98bf6d6640 @strict=true, @collation=nil, @extra="auto_increment", @name="id", @cast_type=#<ActiveRecord::Type::Integer:0x007f98bf6e7490 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=8, @range=-9223372036854775808...9223372036854775808>, @sql_type="bigint(20)", @null=false, @default=nil, @default_function=nil>
```

It has limit=8 and a range that far exceeds the value I'm trying to save, but I still get the same error:

```
2.2.2 :045 > MyModelName.new.save
RangeError: 2147483657 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4
```

It is interesting to note that the autoincrement value is getting updated, even though the record is not saved. If I try again, the ID value is incremented:

```
RangeError: 2147483658 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4
```

Version info

```
activerecord (4.2.5.1)
mysql2 (0.3.18)
```

Comment: silly question: did you try reloading your rails console ?

Comment: Yes - I even went so far as to restart my whole dev computer. Still get the same error (except it reset the autoincrement value - apparently that's stored in memory)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any update/after_save callbacks that propogate this value to a similar foreign key that needs to be resized as well ?

Comment: No, nothing like that. I was not able to reproduce the issue on a simplified project that I just created, so I'm thinking we might have a custom function somewhere overriding a method in the mysql adapter or active record. I'm going to check in with another developer on my team

Comment: cool. hope you find the issue. update the thread so that i'll learn too :)

Comment: turns out I had an erroneous record on my test machine that had the max ID, but we don't actually have that many records in our production data, so the expansion of the ID field to bigint was unnecessary. It will have to remain a mystery why I couldn't get the new ID to work. I'm thinking now that my migration failed the first couple times I ran it and somehow corrupted the db field or autoincrement. Or something. Embarrassing!

Comment: Ha! somethings will remain a mystery :) glad things worked out though.